# Is there any good way to switch different context between Unit Test and Release. in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some context in code to be switched depending on whether it is running under test or release.
Say in my product coding:

```
PublishRequest(); // the real one
//PublishRequestPsudo(); // the one want to be run during unit test
```

The way I am thinking about is make a TestFlag class:

```
if (!TestFlag.PublishFlag)
{
    PublishRequest();
}
else
{
    PublishRequestPsudo();
}
```

This seems verbose if I have many place to do that. Is there any good pattern to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pretty good way to acheive the same is [Dependency Injection/Inversion Of Control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Another good resource on this is [Caching ArchitectureTestability, Dependency Injection and Multiple Providers](http://dotnetslackers.com/_NET/re-394488_Caching_Architecture_Testability_Dependency_Injection_and_Multiple_Providers.aspx)

Comment: So using a switch with TestFlag class will cause redundant dependency right?

Comment: @demaxSH: Its not redundant dependancy, rather i seems to me like hardcoding for testing.

Comment: The production code should not have extra code for testability.. rather rework your design to make it testable. Use roles, whose implementations can easily/non-intrusively be substituted by unit tests.